# validate specified image on laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

how can i validate an image (not in $_FILES)

this is not work

```
$input = array('image' => 'image.txt');
$rules = array('image' => array('Image'));

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if($validator->fails()){
    return $validator->messages();
} else {
            return true
    }
```

always return true

There is Laravel validate image methods

```
/**
 * Validate the MIME type of a file is an image MIME type.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validateImage($attribute, $value)
{
    return $this->validateMimes($attribute, $value, array('jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'));
}

/**
 * Validate the MIME type of a file upload attribute is in a set of MIME types.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  array   $value
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validateMimes($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    if ( ! $value instanceof File or $value->getPath() == '')
    {
        return true;
    }

    // The Symfony File class should do a decent job of guessing the extension
    // based on the true MIME type so we'll just loop through the array of
    // extensions and compare it to the guessed extension of the files.
    foreach ($parameters as $extension)
    {
        if ($value->guessExtension() == $extension)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate a file, you have to pass the `$_FILES['fileName']` array to the validator.

```
$input = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
```

and I am pretty sure that your validation rules must be lowercase.

```
$rules = array(
    'image' => 'image'
);
```

Notice that I have the removed the array from the value.

For more information, check out the [validation docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-image)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you open the form for files!

Make sure it has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in the from tag.

Comment: Laravel already does it? Its validation of file with rule `image` already checks for mime-types